# how to use OAuth 2 sccess token?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

google.api_core.exceptions.Unauthenticated: 401 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

```
[
    reason: "ACCOUNT_STATE_INVALID"
    domain: "googleapis.com"
    metadata:{key: "service"
value: "pubsub.googleapis.com"
}
metadata: {
key: "method"
value: "google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.Publish"
}
metadata:{
key: "email"
value: "trackings-tracelog-to-bigtable@aftership-test.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}]
```

I can't use google credential to request pubsub lib. always report OAuth 2 access token error.

Comment: You would need to share your code and the means you are using to provide the credentials to the library.